# Implementation of some functions of a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I have implemented few functions of a linked list. Feedback is welcome.
**Please note** I have specifically avoided using pointer to pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Node data structure inside the linked list.
struct node {
   int data;
   struct node* next;
};

struct node* BuildOneTwoThree(void);
void printList(struct node  * head);
int getListLength(struct node * head);
struct node* insertAtFront(struct node * const head, int value);
int getAt(struct node *  head, int index, int *);
struct node* insertAtBack(struct node* head, int value);

int main() {

  // Create sample linked list and obtain pointer to the head.
  struct node * head = NULL; 
  head = insertAtBack(head, 700);
  head = insertAtFront(head, 12);
  head = insertAtFront(head, 3);
  head = insertAtFront(head, 5);
  head = insertAtFront(head, 55);
  head = insertAtBack(head, 333);

  printList(head);

  printf("List length is: %d\n", getListLength(head));

  return 0;  
}

///
//
// Create a sample linked list with three nodes
// connected to each other.
//
// Parameter:
//  nothing.
// Return
//  pointer to the head of the linked list that was built.
//
struct node* BuildOneTwoThree(void)
{
  struct node * one = NULL;
  struct node * two = NULL; 
  struct node * three = NULL;

  //
  // Allocate memory for (three) nodes
  //
  one = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  if(one == NULL) return NULL;

  two = malloc(sizeof(struct node));  
  if(two == NULL)
  {
    free(one);
    return NULL;
  }

  three = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  if(three == NULL)
  {
    free(one);
    free(two);
    return NULL;
  }

  // Set data values for each node
  one->data = 1;
  two->data = 2;
  three->data = 3;

  // Chain nodes
  one->next = two;
  two->next = three;
  three->next = NULL;

  // Return pointer to head node
  return one;


}

///
//
// Print contents of each node in the linked list.
//
// Parameter:
//  head: pointer to the head of the node
// Return
//  nothing. Prints content of each node on console.
//
void printList(struct node * head)
{

   int i = 0;
   int x = 0;

   // If the list is empty, there is nothing to print.
   if(NULL == head)
     return;    

   // First let's get number of nodes in the linked list.
   int length = getListLength(head);

   // Let's iterate over the nodes now.
   for(i = 0; i<length; i++)
   {
     // Get value of i-th node
     if(-1 == getAt(head, i, &x))
          break;

     printf("%d \n", x);

   }
}


///
//
// Get number of nodes in the linked list.
//
// Parameter:
//  head: pointer to the head of the node
// Return
//  number of nodes in the linked list.
//
int getListLength(struct node * head)
{

   int size = 0;

   // If head pointer is NULL - the size of the list is 0.
   if(NULL == head)
     return size;   


   while(1)
   {
     // Since head is not NULL, there is at least one node in the list.
     size++;

     // Move to the next node
     head = head->next;

     // If the next node is NULL, stop.
     if(head == NULL) 
    return size;
   }


}

///
//
// Insert new node in the beginning of the linked list.
//
// Parameter:
//  head: pointer to the head of the node
//  value: value for the new linked list node
// Return
//  Pointer to the linked list which contains the added node in the beginning.
//
struct node* insertAtFront(struct node * const head, int value)
{

    // Create a new node - and check if creation was success
    struct node* result = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(result == NULL) return NULL;

    result->next = NULL;

    // If head is NULL, just return the new node.
    if(head == NULL)
    {
       result->data = value;
       return result;
    }   

    // Otherwise make the new node point where head was pointing, and return the new node as new head
    result->next = head;
    result->data = value;
    return result;


}


///
//
// Get element at some index. Index starts from 0.
//
// Parameter:
//  head: pointer to the head of the node
//  index: 0 based index of element we wish to retrieve
//  value: [out] parameter where the value of the node found will be written
// Return
//  -1 on error 0 on success.
//
int getAt(struct node  * head, int index, int * value)
{

   int currIndex = 0;

   // Make sure requested index of element is not out of bounds
   if(index >= getListLength(head))
     return -1;

   // If the head pointer is NULL, there is no point in searching further.
   if(head == NULL)
   {
      return -1;
   }

   // Start an infinite loop
   while(1)
   {
     if(index == currIndex)
     {
    *value = head->data; // Return value of the index-th element
        return 0;   
     }

     head = head->next;

     currIndex++;

   }


}



struct node* insertAtBack(struct node* head, int value)
{

    struct node * current = head;

    int length = 0;
    int i = 0;

    // Create a new node - and check if creation was success
    struct node* result = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(result == NULL) return NULL;

    result->next = NULL;
    result->data = value;  

    // If initial list is empty just return the new node.
    if(current == NULL)
    {
        return result;
    }

    // Get list length
    length = getListLength(current);


    for(i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
    {
      current = current->next;
    }

    current->next = result;

    return head;


}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 1):

**Doing extra work in printList**

The thing that most catches my eye, is that in `printList`, you first get the length of the list, then iterate over it, calling `getAt` on every iteration:

```
 int length = getListLength(head);
 for(i = 0; i<length; i++) {
     if(-1 == getAt(head, i, &x))
          break;
```

This means that you're iterating starting from the beginning again and again for every node in the list, i.e. doing \$O(n^2)\$ work, instead of \$O(n)\$ which would be enough for simply iterating over the list.

The point of a linked list is that you don't need to know where the end is when you start walking it, and that you can hold valid pointers to the nodes in the middle and do something useful with them. Here, every operation starts from `head` instead.

For printing, I'd rather make a loop similar to when you count the nodes:

```
struct node *p = head;
while(p) {
    printf("%d\n", p->value); // or count here
    p = p->next;
}
```

I changed the `while(1)` loop on purpose, I feel putting the test in the `while` statement makes it more readable, since there is only one exit condition anyway. Also, you don't need a separate `if` for `head == NULL`, since `while` does the test first.

**Always starting from head**

In addition to `printList`, the other functions you have, also always take the `head` node. For `insertAtFront` this is obvious, and you might want an `insertAtBack` function too that can start from the head. But what about inserting in the middle, in an arbitrary point? The (theoretical) [advantage of linked lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Tradeoffs) is that insertion is \$O(1)\$, and as above, always searching from the beginning thrashes that.

So, in the least, you should add a function for inserting after a given node, something like

```
struct node *insertHere(struct node *here, struct node *newone) {
    newone->next = here->next;
    here->next = newone;
}
```

Also, I'd separate the functions of creating a node, and inserting a node at a given point, since there might well be cases where you just want to move a given node from one list to another, and doing a malloc/free pair at that point is a waste.

**What if the list is empty**

The funny thing is, that having a `head` pointer that is `NULL` when the list is empty, seems natural, but it requires always checking if the list is empty. You can see this in that the insertion functions specifically test for `head == NULL`, and you have to assign to `head` in the main program after calling them. It also makes adding in the middle a bit difficult, since if the list is empty, you'd need to change the `head` pointer (to point to the newly added item), but if it isn't empty, you don't want to touch `head` at all, for efficiency's sake. A bit of a conundrum, I'd say.

One solution would be to make a separate structure for the list in general, which would contain a pointer to the first item, and possibly some metadata about the list. (e.g. it could cache the list size if that is often needed, and a pointer to the last item to make it faster to add at the end.)

That has the downside that all additions would require handing out a pointer to the main structure, *and* the node being operated on. Having no actual nodes would still be a special case, too.

Another way is to just demand that the list never be empty(!). This is easiest to do by having a node that contains some invalid value ([a sentinel node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Sentinel_nodes)), something that is skipped by all functions actually handling the data. Sounds like a bit of a waste, though it's just a trivial version of a separate main structure, with the advantage that this time all the structs and pointers would be the *same type*.

(Or rather, build the list functions such that they don't handle empty lists. The application program could of course have a pointer to a list node, that happens to be `NULL`.)

Comment: I added also code for insertInMiddle - please look at that too. And please try to isolate in your feedback which concerns are efficiency related and which are actually problems or bugs in the code. Because my full code as it is now, works - do you have any problems with it apart from efficiency ???

Comment: @user200400, Since were talking about data structures in general, I would call going from \$O(n)\$ to \$O(n^2)\$ a bug instead of just a (minor) efficiency issue. Similarly, \$O(1)\$ insertions are pretty much _the point_ of linked lists, since otherwise you could just use arrays which might at least make the code a bit simpler by avoiding most pointer games. (Though with C arrays inserts in the middle need to be done manually.) Consider the performance differences of different data structures, presented [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Tradeoffs) (among others).

Comment: I would like to repeat myself: do you see in the code - as it is now in question - any problem apart from efficiency??

Answer (score 0):

You are not lazy enough, keep the code slim.

```
int getListLength(struct node * list)
{
   int size = 0;
   while(list != null)
   {
     size++;
     list = list->next;
   }
   return size;
}

struct node* insertAtFront(struct node * const head, int value)
{
    struct node* result = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(result == NULL) return NULL; // hmmm

    result->next = head;
    result->data = value;
    return result;
}

struct node* insertAtBack(struct node* head, int value)
{
    struct node* result = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(result == NULL) return NULL;

    result->next = NULL;
    result->data = value;  

    if (head == NULL)
    {
         return result;
    }
    struct node * current = head;
    while (current->next != NULL)
    {
         current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = result;
    return head;
}

// For comparison using an alias, pointer to pointer
struct node* insertAtBack(struct node* head, int value)
{
    struct node ** current = &head;
    while (*current != null)
    {
      current = &(*current)->next;
    }
    struct node* result = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(result == NULL) return NULL;

    result->next = NULL;
    result->data = value;  
    *current = result;
    return head;
}

struct node* insertOrdered(struct node* head, int value)
{
    struct node ** current = &head;
    while (*current != null && value < (*current)->value)
    {
      current = &(*current)->next;
    }
    struct node* result = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(result == NULL) return NULL;

    result->next = *current;
    result->data = value;  
    *current = result;
    return head;
}
```

Comment: @ilkkachu That aliasing technique is for altering either `head` or some `node.next`. Here insertAtBack uses it when head is null, to fill it with result. One also could handle two cases head null or not. But as only C (and not Java for instance) can do aliasing, I wanted to show this shorter code.

Comment: please see my note in the beginning about double pointers

Comment: @user200400 Thanks for "pointing" out my mistake. Added the correct insertAtBack, but actually ilkkachu made a nicer review.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would get rid of `struct` keyword and append `const` to constant pointers.

While `getAt` returns non-value, but successful status, I would name it `tryGetAt` and change type of result to `bool`. It makes you intentions clearer.

```
node* BuildOneTwoThree(void);
void printList(const node* head);
int getListLength(const node* head);
node* insertAtFront(node* head, int value);
bool tryGetAt(const node* head, int index, int *value);
node* insertAtBack(node* head, int value);
node* insertInTheMiddle(node* head, int index, int value);
```

Well. Functions `printList`, `getListLength` contains the **list** word, but other functions aren't. It's better to name functions with same rules, f.e. `list_print`, `list_get_length`, `list_insert_at_front` and so on. Cause you like camel-case, they may be `listPrint`, `listGetLength` etc. `BuildOneTwoThree` seems test function but anyway — `listCreate123`. `The` in `InsertInTheMiddle` is not necessary.

```
node* listCreate123(void);
void listPrint(const node* head);
int listGetLength(const node* head);
node* listInsertAtFront(node* head, int value);
bool tryGetAt(const node* head, int index, int *value);
node* listInsertAtBack(node* head, int value);
node* listInsertInMiddle(node* head, int index, int value);
```

Now, the code of `listCreate123` is too complex and volatiles the DRY principle. Let add simple helper function `createNode`:

```
static node* createNode(int data, node* next)
{
  node* result = malloc(sizeof(node));

  if(result == NULL)
    return NULL;

  result->data = data;
  result->next = next;

  return result;
}

node* listCreate123(void)
{
    return createNode(1, createNode(2, createNode(3, NULL)));
}
```

Wow. Shorter and simpler.

Now `listPrint`. Typical [Shlemiel the painter's algorithm](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html). Rewrite to make the implementation **O(n)** instead of **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**.

```
void listPrint(const node* head)
{
   while(head != NULL)
   {
      printf("%d\n", head->data);
      head = head->next;
   }
}
```

Similar `listGetLength`:

```
void listGetLength(const node* head)
{
   int result = 0;

   while(head != NULL)
   {
      result++
      head = head->next;
   }

   return result;
}
```

More complex `tryGetAt`:

```
bool tryGetAt(const node* head, int index, int* value)
{
  if(index < 0 || head == NULL)
    return false;

  while(index-- > 0)
  {
    head = head->next;

    if(head == NULL)
      return false;
  }

  *value = head->data;
  return true;
}
```

Three insertion function. `listInsertAtFront` is very simple:

```
node* listInsertAtFront(node* head, int value)
{
  return createNode(value, head);
}
```

`listInsertAtBack` and `listInsertInMiddle` both are require helper internal function `insertAfter`:

```
void listInsertAfter(node* before, int value)
{
  before->next = createNode(value, before->next);
}

node* listInsertAtBack(node* head, int value)
{
  if(head == NULL)
    return NULL;

  node* last = head;

  while(last->next != NULL)
    last = last->next;

  listInsertAfter(last, value);

  return head;
}

node* listInsertInMiddle(node* head, int index, int value)
{
  if(index < 0 || head == NULL)
    return NULL;

  node* current = head;

  while(index-- > 0)
  {
    current = current->next;

    if(current == NULL)
      return NULL;
  }

  listInsertAfter(current, value);

  return head;
}
```

Finally, `listFree`. You should free every nodes in list, so:

```
void listFree(node* head)
{
  while(head != NULL)
  {
    node* tmp = head->next;
    free(head);
    head = tmp;
  }
}
```

Comment: any words about the freeList? Btw listCreate123 I am not using anymore - but thanks. I remembered I had removed that

Comment: @user200400 Append freeList.

Comment: Thanks but I think you gave too much feedback. Incorporating all of your feedback would require rewriting most of my code. I tested my code and seems to work so far. This is most important for me. I don't want to rewrite it just for small efficiency reasons. If you see some serious bugs in my code please highlight that in bold in your answer. Thanks again

Comment: Sorry, but no. Code review required to make the code better: simpler, faster, easier to maintain and fix. So if you doesn't want to rewrite your code, you doesn't need the review.

Comment: Well then you should provide your review in a more readable way: highlight where you found bugs, deficiencies in functionality, and highlight separately places where you suggest optimization. Right now your review is a mess to read